# Mysql support this kind of "with" sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In postgres, I use this kind of sql often.

```
with list (id, name) as ( 
    values 
    (1004007, 'aaa'), 
    (1002147, 'bbb'), 
    (1004493, 'ccc'), 
    (1007978, 'ddd'), 
    (1005218, 'eee'), 
    (1005507, 'fff') 
)
select * from list;
```

Dose Mysql support that kind of sql ?

Comment: I suspect not - but feel free to [try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0).

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: The `VALUES` statement is new in MySQL 8.0.19 (earlier versions won't support it), and the syntax is a little different than what you show. I haven't tried it in combination with a CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select`:

```
with list (id, name) as ( 
      select 1004007, 'aaa' union all 
      select 1002147, 'bbb' union all 
      select 1004493, 'ccc' union all
      select 1007978, 'ddd' union all
      select 1005218, 'eee' union all
      select 1005507, 'fff'
     )
select l.*
from list l;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=144b1dd996fc6898abe3c5ee11ae18d2) is a db<>fiddle.  Note:  This also works in Postgres.

Pre 8.0 versions of MySQL do not support `with`.  You can create a derived table:

```
select list.*
from (select 1004007, 'aaa' union all 
      select 1002147, 'bbb' union all 
      select 1004493, 'ccc' union all
      select 1007978, 'ddd' union all
      select 1005218, 'eee' union all
      select 1005507, 'fff'
     ) list;
```

This can then be used just a like a table reference.

Answer (score 0):

Later 8.0 in mysql , we can use it like bellow

```
with 
list (a, b, c) as (VALUES 
ROW('1',-2,3), 
ROW('5',7,9), 
ROW('4',6,8)
)
select * from list;
```